# subquery MY SQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm doing a searcher in my website and I need to include all the constraits that I need in my select query.

In my searcher the user can write a key word, write a min price and a max price, and choose between some categories, but it's not necessary to find a result by filling all the fields, as a user you have to be able to find by filling everything or just by one of them, so I have to do a constrait to separate it.

I'm trying something like:

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1']; //name - type = text
$var2 = $_POST['var2']; //min price - type = integer
$var3 = $_POST['var3']; //max price - type = integer
$var4 = $_POST['var4']; //array of categories

$select_query = "SELECT * FROM objects WHERE x=1";

if($var1 != NULL || $var1 != ''){
"AND name like '%$var1%'"
}

if(($var2 != NULL || $var2 != '') AND ($var3 != NULL || $var3 != '')){
"AND price=>$var2 AND price =>$var3'"
}
```

Here I have an extra problem because I want to return any category that the user selected, so first it has to be an AND to continue the query, but then it has to be an OR, between categories, the problem is that the last one will fail.

```
    if($var4 != NULL || $var4 != ''){
      " AND(";
         foreach $var4 as $cat){
         "id_category = $cat OR";
         }
      ")";
    }
```

Any tip? thanks!

Comment: Just by looking at your code and not testing it, it seems like that last part is failing because there will always be a trailing OR at the end of it. so you get something like `... AND (id_category = $cat OR id_category = $cat OR)` which causes a syntax error

Comment: do the field names correspond to the db column names?

Comment: Yes , that's one of the problems, but I don't know how can I solve it. 

@RamRaider yes they do!

Comment: Use `implode()` to create a string like `AND id_category IN (1,2,5,7)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PHP's implode function:

```
" AND(" . implode("OR ", $var4) . ")"
```

You'll want to make sure $var is non empty array.

Also, please read up on SQL Injection and how to properly escape SQL queries with PHP so that your code interacting with your database is secure:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I was doing wrong the query!

The solution was:

```
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM objects WHERE x=1";

if($var1 != NULL || $var1 != ''){
$select_query = "AND name like '%$var1%'"
}
```

I did the last example with a for.

Thank you all!